# Selenium Webdriver Problem cannot open google chrome

Tags: java

chrome driver 77
chrome version 77

```
Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}) on port 38929
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created
from disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JCFLT7B', ip: '192.168.1.113', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
```

Comment: This looks like a version incompatibility issue. Try to use an older version of chrome. v76 would work fine I believe.

Comment: should i download chrome version76 or chrome driver 76

Comment: Please try downgrading both the chrome driver as well as chrome. I believe you are using JDK 8.

Comment: i have dowanloaded both

Comment: but again showing same error

Comment: i am using chrome browser 77 and chrome driver 77

Comment: please help me out

Comment: Try using chrome driver 75 and google chrome 76.

Comment: nothing is working sir

Comment: same error is coming

Answer (score 1):

1. Versions of driver and of Chrome should match.
2. In Chrome, disable autoupdates. Otherwise after launching Chrome will be updated and *can* became incompatible with Java driver.

Comment: ya both are matching

Comment: i have disabled agian facing same issue

Comment: After disabling, check the Chrome version. May be it is already updated and you have the newest version instead of particular older version that you wanted.

Comment: i ahve checked it is same version 77 and chrome dribver is also 77

Comment: I have checked now. Chrome 77 + Chrome Drive 77. It worked well with different versions of Selenium Web Driver: with 3.0.0 as well as with 3.141.59. I suppose it can be connected with your configuration. Please show us the code how you create web driver in your test. And also tell us the Java version you use.